# Update instance variable in Textarea (Java)

Tags: java, swing

Im trying to create an code that will update and add an instance variable with 1 every three seconds. This is the current piece of code that I have

**Timer:**

```
 public rityta() {
        initComponents();
            //Timer
        time = new Timer(1000, null);
        time.addActionListener(this);
        time.start();
    }


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    Object o = ae.getSource();
     if (o == time) {
        tid++;
        if (tid % 3 == 0) { //Every three seconds
            for (int i = 0; i < djur.size(); i++) {              //Wont start until something's been added to tha ArrayList named "djur"
                djur.get(i).setValue(djur.get(i).getValue()+1);  //Get the instance variable and adds one
                System.out.println(djur.get(i).getValue());      //Just a proof of concept that it works, the output window updated every three seconds and adds 1
                jTextArea2.update(jTextArea2.getGraphics());     // Is this needed?
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**The Problem**
Now, since the output updates every three seconds with the new instance variable from my class, my Textarea that displays the instance variable should update as well, right? But it wont. So how do I make the new instance variable update in my Textarea as well?

Since my TextArea also contains the ToString of my ArrayList, the TextArea looks something like this:

```
Name: aaa    Value: 10
Name: bbb    Value: 10
```

And I just want to update the instance variable of 10 to add 1 every three seconds. :)

Comment: there is an issue with "if(o==time)" this is not how you compare objects in java.Use .equals

Comment: @mm8511: not true at least not in this situation. He's wanting to do a reference comparison here, and so the `==` operator is exactly what he should be using.

Comment: @hovercraftfullofeels good catch.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't expect the JTextArea update automatically as you never call `setText(...)` or `append(...)` on it, and just because a variable has been changed, its String representation within the JTextArea will not automatically change when this occurs. For the JTextArea to update, either these methods must be called (setText or append) on it, or you must modify the JTextArea's Document (but do so with care).

As for this: `jTextArea2.update(jTextArea2.getGraphics());` You never have a need to do this, nor should you ever want to do this.

As an aside #1, I wonder if you really want to be using a JList or JTable and not a JTextArea, but I can't say for sure without more knowledge of the details of your problem-space and your code.

Aside #2: Please consider changing your user name. You, like all of us, were born ignorant but hopefully not stupid as the former can be improved upon through diligent effort while the latter cannot.

---

Regarding:

> Since my TextArea also contains the ToString of my ArrayList, the TextArea looks something like this:
>
> ```
> Name: aaa    Value: 10
> Name: bbb    Value: 10
> ```
>
> And I just want to update the instance variable of 10 to add 1 every three seconds. :)

You appear to be displaying *mutable* tabular data, data that changes frequently, and so in this situation I think that you're far better off using a tool that is built for just this sort of situation, a JTable. If you did this, then you would only have to change the pertinent cell's data within the JTable's model when that reference data has been updated, and since you'll wire the model to notify its view (the JTable itself) whenever it changes, your data display will automatically update.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. setText or append will not really work in this situation since the textarea also displays the ToString's of my ArrayList. For example it says "Name: aaa Value: 10  \n Name: bbb Value: 10, and I just want to update the value of 10 to 11 every three sec of both. Any idea of solving that?

Comment: @Stupid: please improve the question itself, including telling the full story, and if possible posting a valid [mcve], a minimal program, small enough to be posted in your question as code-formatted text, one that compiles and runs, and that demonstrates your problem for us. It's not your whole program, it doesn't have all it's functionality, but again it runs for us, and it demonstrates the problem for us.